# Pandas to_sql gives ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, pandas-to-sql

I try to write pandas dataframe to Oracle and with to_sql method, sometimes writes successfully and sometimes gives  "(cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error" with same dataframe.

I checked most of the oracle errors for ORA-03106 but could not understand why it is working sometimes and not working for another try.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


oracle_connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@{hostname}: 
{port}/{database}'

engine = create_engine(
    oracle_connection_string.format(
        username= 'user',
        password= 'pass',
        hostname='.....',
        port='..',
        database='sampledb',
    )
)

dataset.to_sql('TEST_TABLE',engine,if_exists='append',index =False)
```

Comment: Are you dropping and recreating the table during the execution of the Python process (which is never recommended in Oracle)?  It could be the statement cache getting out of sync - you could disable this but it will affect performance, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=stmtcachesize&check_keywords=yes&area=default#

Comment: Actually table does not exist in database. I create it from pandas dataframe.Even if it exists, i think to_sql command with 'append' will not drop and recreate the table.